# How to resample a list of Images

Tags: image-processing, image, image3d

I have a list of picture(Noting the ordering)

first:
[image]
second:
[image]
third:
[image]
forth:
[image]

My target is get the 3D'image,Now I get the `mask` of it like following(If you use it,you should `Binarize` it by yourself)

[image]
Then
[image]
I can get the result by `slices`

```
Image3D[slices, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

As you can see,the color transition of surface is so bad that you can see it clearly that it is made up of 4 pictures.For the smooth color transition we needs some sampled picture,then we use the `Image3D` build 3D-image.So the question is how to resample a list of image.If the target is a list of number,we can use `ArrayResample` like as:

```
In[1]:= ArrayResample[{1,2,3,4,5},9]
Out[1]= {1,3/2,2,5/2,3,7/2,4,9/2,5}
```

But the list is picture now.How to do it?Can Any body have a try?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`ImageResize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageResize.html) to resample the z-direction for your purpose.

```
imgs = Import /@ {
    "https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXvgm.jpg", 
    "https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJJnL.jpg", 
    "https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdbmR.jpg", 
    "https://i.stack.imgur.com/auRS8.jpg"};
mask = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/6S4Vj.png"];
slices = ImageMultiply[#, mask] & /@ imgs;

With[{img3d = Image3D[slices]},
 ImageResize[img3d, ImageDimensions[img3d]*{1, 1, 100}, 
  Resampling -> "Linear"]
 ]
```

With this, you get a smooth transition. You probably won't need 100 slices, so please adapt the resampling size and the even the `Resampling` method as you like.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @halirutan thanks for the edit; didn't have time to use the images in the question.

Comment: I'm sorry I rewrote your whole answer, but it is basically exactly what you had just with the original data which will hopefully end in more upvotes. I didn't see your answer until I had the code written down, so I decided to edit yours. I hope that's OK. +1 btw.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to resample the data, not only the resulting Image

```
imgData = ImageData /@ slices

(* Resample for 10 points in each dimension) *)
Image /@ ArrayResample[imgData, 10 {1, 1, 1}] // Image3D

(* If you need finer-grained z sampling) *)
Image /@ ArrayResample[imgData, 10 {2, 1, 1}] // Image3D[#, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}] &
```

Here's a sample 3d Image resampled from 3x3 to 10x10.

[image: 3x3 image into 10x10 image]

Comment: Transform the `10 {1, 1, 1}` to `10 {1, Sequence@@ImageDimensions[mask]}`will fit me more,And thanks for your new thinking.