# How to realize a Harmonic Tool like as CorelDraw

Tags: image-processing, image

I get a rectangle and a circle like following:

[image]

[image]

The `Harmonic Tool` of `CorelDraw` can transition the rectangle to circle smoothly like this
[image]

So how can I get the transitional images from the given rectangle to the given circle.There is a similar topic of me.[How to resample a list of Images](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/100209/how-to-resample-a-list-of-images/100211#100211),If we use the method of @shrx we cannot get result that I want

```
With[{img3d = Image3D[imgs]}, 
 ImageResize[img3d, ImageDimensions[img3d]*{1, 1, 100}, 
  Resampling -> "Linear"]]
```

[image]

Comment: its not clear what you are starting with.  Are you drawing a figure with drawing tools? Are you starting with a raster image (example needed)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a method that uses some very basic image processing to work for fairly general figures (any convex black-and-white shape, I believe). First, I get the images:

```
In[1]:= rect = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkv8a.png"];
        circ = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gy44u.png"];
```

Now, I use `ImageValuePositions` and `Binarize` to find the points of the drawing (note that `Binarize` flips black and white), and `MeshPrimitives` and `ConvexHullMesh` to eliminate redundant points introduced but the thickness of the lines and to put the points in a sensible order:

```
centered[p_] := Transpose[Transpose[p] - Mean@p];
lines[p_] := MeshPrimitives[ConvexHullMesh[p], 1];
points[img_] :=
  With[{p = ImageValuePositions[Binarize@img, White]},
   centered@DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[lines[p] /. Line -> Identity, 1]]];

In[3]:= startPoints = points@circ;
        endPoints = points@rect;
```

Now seems like a good time to check that things look right:

```
In[4]:= Graphics[{Line[startPoints], Line[endPoints]}]
Out[4]=
```

> [image: circle and rectange]

Next, I want to linearly interpolate between these sets of points, which means setting up correspondences between the two sets of points. I do this using `Nearest` and `GroupBy`:

```
correspondance[start_, end_] :=
  With[{
    sorted = SortBy[{start, end}, Length],
    dir = If[Length[start] < Length[end], Forward, Backward]
   },
   {dir, GroupBy[Last@sorted, Nearest@First@sorted]}];
```

I pick the direction because I want to make sure that if I have more points in one list, the many-to-one mapping is done properly by `GroupBy`. Now it's just a matter of turning this into a linear interpolation:

```
paired[corr_Association] := Transpose[
   Flatten[KeyValueMap[Tuples@*List, corr], 1]];

order[Backward, paired_] := Reverse@paired
order[Forward, paired_] := paired;

lerp[{dir : (Forward | Backward), corr_}] :=
  Replace[order[dir, paired@corr],
    {start_, end_} :>
    With[{diff = end - start},
     Function[t, start + t*diff]]];
```

Now we just plug everything in:

```
In[8]:= l = lerp@correspondance[startPoints, endPoints];
```

Here's an animation of `Table[Graphics@Line[l[t]], {t, 0, 1, 0.05}]`:

[image]

Comment: The question is been closed.I feel so sorry for your nice answer.

Answer (score 6):

Not exactly what you are asking for but the specific case of circle->square can be done mathematically as both are special cases of hyperellipses:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[ParametricPlot[  {#[[1]] x, #[[2]] (1 - 
          x^(2^n))^(1/(2^n))} , {x, 0, 1}, AspectRatio -> 1] & /@ {{1,
      1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, -1}, {1, -1}}, Axes -> False, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}] , {{n, 1}, 1, 8}]
```

[image]

as another more general approach if you can get your graphics into line form with the same number of points in each you can do a simple interpolation. Example:

```
n = 160; (*must be multiple of 8*)
c = Table[ {-Cos[2 Pi x/n + Pi/4] , -Sin[2 Pi x/n + Pi/4]}, {x, 0, n}];
r = Join[
   Table[ {8 x/n , -1}, {x, -n/8, n/8 - 1}], 
   Table[ {1, 8  x/n}, {x, -n/8, n/8 - 1}],
   Table[ {8  x/n, 1}, {x, n/8, -n/8 + 1, -1}], 
   Table[ {-1, 8  x/n}, {x, n/8, -n/8, -1}]
   ];
Manipulate[Graphics[Line[w r + (1 - w ) c]], {w, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: Oh,Sorry for my poor English.Your result is my target.And thanks for your good thinking but a Image-processing method is expected~^_^

Answer (score 5):

In your particular case with `Rectangle` -> `Circle` you can simply use `RoundingRadius`:

```
GraphicsRow@Table[Graphics@Rectangle[{0, 0}, RoundingRadius -> r], {r, 0, .5, .1}]
```

[image]

A general image-based method was discussed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59463).

Comment: Your link help a lot.Thanks~^_^